# Wikidata ontology to Produce a larger subgraph by extracting the subgraphs of some relevant books, birthplace, education institutions, etc

Tags: rdf, ontology, wikidata, rdfs, stardog

I want to load the wikidata ontology in stardog studio to produce a larger subgraph by extracting the subgraphs of some relevant books, birthplace, education institutions from the wikidata. I am not sure from where I can download the wikidata ontology.
I am doing thesis on representation of wikidata in RDF and Property graph and KGTK. For this I have seen the single Entity for instance, Q42 and produce the subgraph of Q42 in RDF, Property graph and KGTK. Now my next task is to produce a larger subgraph by extracting the subgraphs of some relevant books, birthplace, education institutions, etc.

My supervisor has given me just this link https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:WikiProject_Ontology. but i dont know from where i get the wikidata ontologies and how can i load them in stardog studio.

Comment: there is no proper Wikidata ontology online for download afaik, but you could start from here: https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:WikiProject_Ontology

Comment: nevertheless, you can use a SPARQL `CONSTRUCT` query in which you get 1) some books and 2) all outgoing data about those books. Use SPARQL `CONSTRUCT` query if you want a known subset of properties (or just all) - for just all you can also try to use a `DESCRIBE` query.

Comment: regarding the ontology, there is a lots of resources, e.g. https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:WikiProject_Ontology/Mapping and you can walk through the Wiki to get an idea of classes and properties: https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:WikiProject_Ontology/Top-level_ontology_list

Comment: Do you already have your own copy of wikidata? See https://wiki.bitplan.com/index.php/Wikidata_On_Stardog on a successful attempt to get your own copy of wikidata